# How to configure teaming in RHEL 7?

Tags: linux, networking, rhel

I've used [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Network_Team_Using_a_GUI.html) to configure LACP on my server. Now I see "Connecting" on the Team just created:

[image: lacp]

- why "team0" is mentioned twice in the list?
- Why is it "Connecting", not "Connected? Should it be "Connected"?
- How can I verify that my teaming works?

Comment: That looks like you did it wrong. There's also this doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Networking_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Networking_Guide-en-US.pdf

Comment: This is the same doc.

Comment: it seems GUI just don't work well. i've found this method more suitable https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Configure_a_Network_Team_Using-the_Command_Line.html#sec-Creating_a_Network_Team_Using_teamd